# ASP.NET Chart control keeps showing whitespace

Tags: asp.net, charts

I'm using an asp.net chart control to display a pie chart, image below.

http://i39.tinypic.com/ndtzx1.png

I can't find the property (I assume there must be a property) to get rid of the whitespace surrounding the chart.  Does anyone know how to?  I feel like I've tried everything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adjusting the [ChartArea](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456118(v=VS.100).aspx), like this:

```
area.Position = New ElementPosition(0, 0, 100, 100);
area.InnerPlotPosition = New ElementPosition(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

This tells both the [chart area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartarea.position(v=VS.100).aspx) and [plot area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartarea.innerplotposition(VS.100).aspx) it to start at the upper left and go 100% for width and height.